# WGET: Removing 'filename' since it should be rejected

Tags: shell, wget

I am trying to download all the wmv files that have the word 'high' on their name, in a website using wget with the following command:

```
wget -A "*high*.wmv" -r -H -l1 -nd -np -erobots=off http://mywebsite.com -O yl-`date +%H%M%S`.wmv
```

The file starts and finishes downloading but just after it downloads I get

```
Removing yl-120058.wmv since it should be rejected.
```

- Why is that and how could I avoid it?
- How could I make the command to
  spider the whole website for those
  type of files automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the accept list is being checked twice, once before downloading and once after saving. The latter is the behavior you see here ("it's not a bug, it's a feature"):

Your saved file **yl-120058.wmv** does not match your specified pattern **-A "*high*.wmv"** and will be thus rejected and deleted.

Quote from [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files):

> Finally, it's worth noting that the accept/reject lists are matched twice against downloaded files: [..] the local file's name is also checked against the accept/reject lists to see if it should be removed. [..] However, this can lead to unexpected results.